# Why do we use alpine image to create our custom image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Why do we need to add Alpine image during the creation of our custom image? What if I do not add Alpine image while creating a docker file will it throw an error or won't work.

P.S I am a beginner and learning docker.

Comment: What does your custom image do - what are you adding, what programs are you running, what do you depend on from the base OS image? I'd guess it'd fail at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line of you Dockerfile you select which "virtual machine" you want to use.

Comment: If i select Nginx:latest does it mean that i am running Nginx server virtual machine ?

Comment: That's right. But it will be better to call it "image" instead of "virtual machine" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a base image on which you will install all of your library and code to create your own custom image. 
you can use any base image like debian, centos,ubuntu.But you will be certainly biased to any image which is small in size and which has all the repo link. And there come alpine.

From alpine [description](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine#:~:text=Alpine%20Linux%20is%20a%20Linux,utilities%20and%20even%20production%20applications.) 
Alpine Linux is a Linux distribution built around musl libc and BusyBox. The image is only 5 MB in size and has access to a package repository that is much more complete than other BusyBox based images. This makes Alpine Linux a great image base for utilities and even production applications.

To see more benefit and comparison among base image you can check this [one](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/the-3-biggest-wins-when-using-alpine-as-a-base-docker-image)